# Use of unassigned local variable 'KubeClient'

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

Getting an error in c# console application.

> Use of unassigned local variable 'KubeClient'

I tried to use Kubernetes client in my application. But its working with the above error. I know the error is due to uninitialised variable  KubeClient. But i used this way in my webapi project. I don't understand the difference. How do i  initialise with kubernetes client.It show

> is inaccessible due to its protection level

. plz Help me ?

my code is

```
using k8s;
using k8s.Models;


public bool ReadTLSSecretIteratable(string secretname, string namespacename)
        {
            V1Secret sec = null;
            Kubernetes KubeClient;
            try
            {
                 sec = KubeClient.ReadNamespacedSecret(secretname, namespacename);
            }
            catch (Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException httpOperationException)
            {
                var content = httpOperationException.Response.Content;
                Console.WriteLine(content);
                throw httpOperationException;

            }
retrun true;
}
```

Comment: `Kubernetes KubeClient;` just declares the variable. It does not assign any value to it. That's why you are seeing this error. You need to assign value to it by doing `Kubernetes KubeClient; = new KubeClient();` or something

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya . if follow the new object creation. It will show is inaccessible due to its protection level
which means these can only be accessed by the class itself or any class which derives

Comment: @junealex I am not aware of how `Kubernetes` class can be instantiated or the fact that handholding will be needed..... using `new` keyword is the most known way in C#. It doesn't mean that it literally has to be `new Kubernetes()` but I intend to suggest to initialize the class instance by using appropriate constructor or any other applicable way (using Factory or DI) in the current situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question uninitialised variableis due to error.  follow the code

```
Kubernetes KubeClient ;
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
//for local testing BuildDefaultConfig && for cluster testing InClusterConfig
KubeClient = new Kubernetes(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get "using unassigned variable error", well, if your variable is unassigned. This is the case here:

```
Kubernetes KubeClient;
```

KubeClient variable has no assigned value. If you wrote:

```
Kubernetes KubeClient = null;
```

than the compile time error would go away, because now the value is NULL. That would not solve the problem though, because obviously you cannot call methods on variables that are null (have no value), and you would have a null reference exception at runtime.

Normal way to initialize a variable is with new:

```
Kubernetes KubeClient = new Kubernetes([pass constructor parameters]);
```

Sometimes there are static factory methods that do complex initializations:

```
Kubernetes KubeClient = Kubernetes.Create([pass constructor parameters]);
```

Finally there is dependency injection which I guess was the case with the webapi project. You register types with the dependency container and than you just get them when you need through constructor or sometimes properties:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(Kubernetes k)
   {
      // Kubernetes is passed by DI container without new keyword.
   }
}
```

Do the following:

- Read on classes initialization in C#, it's crucial to understand it ([Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) for a start)
- Read on dependency injection in general and in .net core, it's very important (e.g. [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection))
- Read documentation of your Kubernetes library, there should be samples and instructions on how to initialize it properly